# Angular (Firebase "Unauthorized")

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, angular16

I have Angular/Firebase project, my admin panel with crud system was working before Firebase was free with one month but after that it's not giving me anymore this service, I upgrade and ready to paid but I'm going on the 401 error and GET and POST methods don't working, please help me I finish this project and I'm on the final step to host this project but I have problems now... help me please

I try to change rules about this data and I have API key and Server key

Comment: I fix it just I write in rules  {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
  }
}